# How to parse data from file Json or Excel

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord.py

I got a code to parse data from json file but still it is incomplete.

```
{"people": [
{"UserID": "xxxxx123", "Name": "Steve", "Sex": "Male", "age": "30"},
{"UserID": "xxxxx124", "Name": "Rachel", "Sex": "Female", "age": "25"},
{"UserID": "xxxxx125", "Name": "George", "Sex": "Male", "age": "22"} ] }

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def mention(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  with open('data.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data['people']:
      if(p['UserID'] == str(member.id)):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, p)
```

when we type `?mention @user` in discord channel bot gives that user data. but i need 2 more help.

1. bot needs to get data from multiple json files or from excel sheets 1 2 3 etc.
2. rather than tagging user it should be `?mention xxxxx123` or `?mention George` to get that user data.

Update error when i run in server:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bosen/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 37, in on_ready
    d = json.load(f)
  File "/home/bosen/.local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/home/bosen/.local/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
MemoryError
```

Comment: What's in the other json files?  You should load all of that information once when you start up your bot (put the code in the `on_ready` event).  Then just loop through the Python objects when the commands are invoked.

Comment: can i get a Sample code how to do that ? also i trying to make that work for user typed names rather than tagging user with User Id.

Comment: Python reads them line by line, so it doens't really matter how big the file is.  2000 json entries isn't that big.  That would allow you to hardcode a single filename.  What would you want to happen if you have multiple users with the name `George`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would re-index the list from the json into a dictionary with two indices: mapping both names and ids to lists of records.

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

index = defaultdict(list)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global index
    for filename in ('data1.json', 'data2.json'):
        with open(filename) as f:
            d = json.load(f)
            for record in d['people']:
                index[record['UserId'].lower()].append(record)
                index[record['Name'].lower()].append(record)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def mention(ctx, *keys):
    for key in keys:
        for record in index[key]:
            await bot.say("{Name} is a {age} year old {Sex}  with id {UserId}".format(**record))
```

Comment: I getting syntax error in `for record on d` can't run bot.

Comment: Typo, it's `for record in d`

Comment: Then you can loop over all the files and load them into the dictionary

Comment: Any idea how to fix this. i need both to work this json command and also lower upper case command also.

Comment: Apply `str.lower` to the keys when you put them in the dictionary.

Comment: At the `index[record['Name']].append(record)`. Make it `index[record['Name'].lower()].append(record)`.  You can do it to the other `append` as well, though I don't think there's a possibility for that to have letters in it.

Comment: Can you tell me what is this error message. when i run 2 or more json files i get error. i added error message in my question above.

Comment: The index is too large to be held in memory as a dictionary.  At this point, you should probably look into switching to a database.  See [this list of `async` compatible database libraries](https://github.com/timofurrer/awesome-asyncio#database-drivers)

Comment: Any solution to bypass `in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
MemoryError`

Comment: You could try using two dictionaries instead of one, but that's not a long term solution.

Comment: Yes i tried that yesterday by adding multiple dictionary it works for only small files. but my main files are big and have many files so its not working. same `MemoryError`

Comment: In that case I think you're more or less stuck with a database.  Write a one-off script to load your data files into the database and use some asynchronous database library to query that database from your discord bot.  I haven't used it extensively, but [`asyncpg`](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg) is pretty good.

Comment: You would have to install that library through `pip`, like any other third party library.